# How to take screenshot in Expo React Native and send to PDF

Tags: react-native, pdf-generation, screenshot, expo

I have a React Native project set up using Expo SDK version 32.

**What I want:** Take a screenshot of a particular view, then put the resulting image into a PDF. I then want to let the user be able to print it. This needs to work in both iOS and Android.

**What I've tried:** See this repo below. All the code is in App.js.
https://github.com/ttchuah/react-native-screenshot

In a nutshell, I am using Expo's [takeSnapshotAsync](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/take-snapshot-async/) method to get a screenshot of a View component. To test that this works, I put the resulting URI into an Image component. (It looks like /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/9DB69B08-C2E3-4AE7-8628-1C635A9E07F4/tmp/ReactABI32_0_0Native/57E0785C-9FFB-44EE-B976-8B6DAEAE7A05.png)

At this point, it works fine.

Then, I try doing this.
Note that the `snapshot` variable is the URI of the screenshot. `pixels` just holds a numeric value.

```
let html = `<img src="${snapshot}" width="100%" style="border:2px solid black; height:${pixels}px; width:${pixels}px;" />`;
            html += '<p>Hello world</p>'

            const pdf = await Print.printToFileAsync({ html });

            return Print.printAsync({ uri: pdf.uri }).catch(error =>
                Alert.alert(error.message)
            );
```

This opens up the device's print-preview screen.

**Results:**

Expected results - the image should show up with a black border around it.

Actual results - the image only shows up on Android. In iOS, it is blank.

I should note that this used to work for iOS on Expo v30. However, I had to upgrade to v32 in order to take advantage of an Expo bug fix, so going back to v30 isn't an option for me.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Thanks for the code, works on my machine

Answer (score -1):

I just tried this code on my iPhone 10 and it works, newest expo SDK, different image URL, therefore your issue lies in the snap-shot.  Probably a breaking change in how the snapshot is generated in iOS.